# Make gulp-uglify ignore specific characters/tokens

Tags: javascript, jquery, gulp, gulp-uglify

I have a javasript code but unfortunately gulp-uglify fails to uglify/minify the code due to the presence of the " ` " character (without quotes). Yep the same character we use here in stackoverflow to hilight words

```
var sb = new ScrollBooster({
      viewport: viewport,
      content: content,
      bounce: true,
      bounceForce: .1,
      textSelection: false,
      friction: 0.14,
      emulateScroll: true,

      onUpdate: function (data) {

        content.scrollLeft = data.position.x;
        content.scrollTop = data.position.y;

        content.style.transform = `translate(${-data.position.x}px,  ${-data.position.y}px)`;
                           //HERE ↑                                

      },
    });
```

Here in the last line this character is used.
Is there is any way that i can make gulp-uglify ignore this character because i do not have any alternative for this code as it is a part of JS library syntax

ERROR:

```
GulpUglifyError: unable to minify JavaScript
Caused by: SyntaxError: Unexpected character '`'
```

Comment: Try Uglify-es, it recognizes es6.  Gulp-uglify does not.

Comment: I'll try it then

Comment: @Mark I don't understand this character Belongs to es6???

Comment: Yes, template strings, see https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-template-strings-2/

Comment: @Mark uglify-es is not maintained anymore so should I use terser or gulp-terser?

Comment: No commits in a year but 2.3 million downloads a week.  I have seen terser recommended but I haven't used it.

Comment: @Mark Thanks for the advice but now I'm using gulp-terser and it works fine for me